# how to add splash screen in blank popup when loading the popup window

Tags: javascript, function, jsp

this function will popup a blank window, after few second only show pdf, during this pop out empty page can add splash screen? or have any suggestion?

```
function popupPDF() {
    page = window.open('', 'policy','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,scrollbars=1,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=750,height=530,left=50,top=10');
    page.focus();
    lockButton();
    document.mainform.Close.disabled = false;
    document.mainform.action = "html2pdf.jsp";
    document.mainform.target = 'policy';
    document.mainform.SUBMITIND.value ="Y";    
    document.mainform.submit();
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add page.document.write

```
    function popupPDF() {
        page = window.open('', 'policy','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,scrollbars=1,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=750,height=530,left=50,top=10');
        page.document.write('<html><head><title>e-ASC - Generate Document</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><style>.loader {border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;border-radius: 50%;border-top: 16px solid #3498db;width: 120px;height: 120px;-webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */animation: spin 2s linear infinite;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}@-webkit-keyframes spin {0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }}@keyframes spin {0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }}</style></head><body><h2 align="center">Please wait ...</h2><div class="loader"/></body></html>');
        page.focus();
        lockButton();
        document.mainform.Close.disabled = false;
        document.mainform.action = "html2pdf.jsp";
        document.mainform.target = 'policy';
        document.mainform.SUBMITIND.value ="Y";    
        document.mainform.submit();
       }
```